# pushviewcontroller doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushviewcontroller

There is a button at the viewcontroller and **when i click** the button **pushviewcontroller** doesn't work.

---

my **appdelegate.m** file :

```
- (BOOL)applicationUIApplication *)application **didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsNSDictionary** *)launchOptions 
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:EK_SCREEN_BOUNDS];

    ExampleViewController *exampleViewController = [ExampleViewController new];

    self.window.rootViewController = exampleViewController;

   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

---

Button click method (in ExampleViewController):

```
mainViewController *frm = [mainViewController new];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:frm animated:YES];
```

**How i can fire button click event ?**

Comment: its hard to read what you actually need, please use the formatting tools and rephrase your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your AppDelegate.m file with following code

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
ExampleViewController *exampleViewController = [ExampleViewController new];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:exampleViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
//self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

> The problem is that you are not initializing rootViewController from
>   navigation controller. So, when you push a view controller on
>   navigation controller it doesn't work. Because you never initialize a
>   navigation controller.

Comment: okey thank you for reply. i do what you say then i click the button openning page is whole black. its not my viewcontroller. what is your opinion

Comment: what is in your mainViewContorller? and also use coding convention like instead of mainViewContorller use file name as MainViewController

Comment: there is any code in my viewcontroller i just only i see my storyboard

Comment: can you share screenshot of storyboard or code inside your myviewcontroller?

Comment: -(void)viewDidLoad{ [super viewDidLoad];  nslog(@"its done"); } thats all :)

Comment: this means it should log "its done" when you click on button. If it logs message then your code is perfect. Now, you only need to add code for your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change in appDelegate.m, need to set navigation controller as root view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:EK_SCREEN_BOUNDS];

ExampleViewController *exampleViewController = [ExampleViewController new];
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:exampleViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigation;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add your ExampleViewController to UINavigationController as below

```
ExampleViewController *exampleViewController = [ExampleViewController new];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:exampleViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = exampleViewController;
```

After this you can do

```
mainViewController *frm = [mainViewController new]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:frm animated:YES];
```

Comment: i added navigationcontroller in my appdelegate file then when i click the button works but openning the viewcontroller is not my viewcontroller.Because its whole black.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** version of what Latit mentioend:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -&gt; Bool {

        let screenBounds:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        var viewController:UIViewController = ViewController();

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: screenBounds);
        var nav:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController);

        self.window?.rootViewController = nav;
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
       return true
    }
}
```

more info:
http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/swift/ui-library/uinavigationcontrolle/set-root-controller